# How to check a URL contains a string and handle the backslashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to to hide a div tag based on the contents of the URL.

However, I want to search more than just "franky"

If my URL is: `//MYWEBSITE/EN/HOME`

I want to check for: `/EN/HOME` not just home. However if I try this it just returns false.

My theory is its the forward slashes but I am `java/jquery` newbie so I don't know. Maybe there is away to escape the / in the search terms.

This code works if I use 'home

Here is my code:

```
if (homepathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('home') >= 0) {

<script>
$(function(){
   var homepathname = window.location.pathname; 
  if (homepathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('/en/home') >= 0) {
        $('#masterHomeBanner').show();
  } else {
        $('#masterHomeBanner').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It is not exactly clear for which urls you want to have `true` and for which one you want to have a `false`, so could you give some more examples where the test should be return `true` and where it should return `false`. `homepathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('/en/home') >= 0` matches each url that contains `/en/home` and because of that also `/test/en/homepage/something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (homepathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('/en/home') > -1) {
somecode...
```

Or:

```
if (homepathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('\/en\/home') > -1) {
somecode...
```

indexOf return the number of character, character is 0 when is first character.
When fails return -1.

```
>>> var x = 'home'; x.indexOf('/en/home');
-1
>>> var x = '/en/home'; x.indexOf('/en/home');
0

>>> var x = '/java/jquery'; x.indexOf('/en/home');
-1
>>> var x = '/java/jquery'; x.indexOf('/java/jquery');
0
```

Comment: Thanks that helped its not the slashes that are my problem. I now realise window.location.pathname is not returning the website domain name. So its coming back /en/home but for various reasons I need a fairly exact match mydoman/en/home the reason being the div tag i am trying to hide is on the homepage of a CMS and so there are really two scenarios. Domain name only and mydomain/en/home - As I said javascript newbie :)

Comment: @WHK why do you add `\ ` before the `/`? The `/` has no special meaning with strings and should therefore not be escaped. While it is true that `\ ` is ignored in that case this behavior is deprecated ([MDN: Values, variables, and literals => Escaping characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters))

Comment: you need document.location?